# FBSDK is ignoring LoginBehavior

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, fbsdk

I am specifying the login behavior to use the app instead of opening a web browser for login, but its totally ignoring it.  Anyone know why?

Here is how I am adding my login button:

```
var loginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
loginButton.loginBehavior = .SystemAccount
loginButton.readPermissions = ["public_profile","user_birthday"]
loginButton.center = self.view.center
loginButton.delegate = self
self.view.addSubview(loginButton)
```

Comment: Pretty sure it is because you are asking for permission. The SystemAccount can't handle that. SystemAccount is not switching app. Switching app was disabled in iOS9 because of changes Apple did

Comment: So, there is no way to use the facebook app for login anymore?

Comment: Correct. After Apple's changes in iOS9 it is not possible anymore